# How to alter div within popup when the popup window is deleted?

Tags: html, jsp, popup

I have a "webpage a", and the "webpage a" gives a jsp popup window. There is a 'search' button inside the jsp popup window.

I made a div in the jsp popup

1) When the popup window first showup, I set div.style.display = 'none'.

2) After the 'search' button is click, I set div.style.display = 'block', so that the popup window cannot be clicked.

3) When the result is returned, since the jsp reload automatically, the div style becomes 'none' again.

However, when the search is still running (and div.style.display = 'block'), if someone close the popup window, the div style is always 'block' because the result never get chance to returned and the jsp page never reloaded.

The problem is after the jsp popup is closed at this circumstances, the div is showing up on my "webpage a", blocking "webpage a", "webpage a" cannot be clicked, the only option is to close "webpage a".

Why when the jsp popup is closed, the div is still there?

And how can I make the div goes away or becomes div.style.display = 'none'? Since the jsp popup has already closed, I cannot make it style.display = 'none' in my jsp. Please help...

Comment: please post your code .

Comment: I am sorry, this can be closed. 
I am an exact newbie, and after much investigation, the problem is not what I first understood to be. And now I have solved the problem already :)))))